# How to get bluetoothClass.Device for tablet?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, tablet, kotlin-android

In my app I am checking the discovered bluetooth devices type by Class bluetoothClass.Device
I want to check if device is tablet or not but I can not find anything to check is device tablet or not.

I am checking devices here as follows:

```
if (device.bluetoothClass.deviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.PHONE_SMART
                ||
                device.bluetoothClass.majorDeviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PHONE)
                pairedDevicesList.add(device)
        }
```

I am not able to check for if discovered device is tablet or not?
I will be thankful for any guidence and helpful material.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Bluetooth specifications, this is [possible](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-numbers/Assigned%20Number%20Types/Assigned%20Numbers.pdf#page=49).

However, it seems that the constant value (284) for a tablet is missing in the current [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device). It stops with [COMPUTER_WEARABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device). So you can try to define your own constant.

Comment: Hey Risto, Thank you so much! Can you please explain how can I define my own constant for tablet?